# Azure WebJob Process Storage Queue Messages Serially

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

We have a need to process messages from an Azure Storage Queue serially, one at a time.

By default, the `JobHostConfiguration.Queues.BatchSize` is set to 16

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/0581fb1610d56a597523fcea67733944efba9541/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHostQueuesConfiguration.cs#L15

And those 16 messages the WebJob pulls off the queue will be processed in parallel. Instead, we need the WebJob to process the messages serially, one at a time.

How can this be achieved?

We are currently forced to set the `BatchSize` to 1, which is not ideal because it introduces a lot of spin up/down time around reading from the message queue.

Clarification: We do not need to enforce first in first out, or guaranteed order processing, just one at a time processing.

Comment: I don't believe azure storage queues guarantee first in first out.  Have you tried using a service bus queue instead.  This page mentions some of the differences: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/

Comment: Is the question asking for _ordered_ processing, or just _one-at-a-time_ processing?

Comment: @DavidMakogon just one-at-a-time processing, no need for FIFO

Answer (score 2):

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Set your BatchSize and MaxDequeueCount to 1,
Set MaxPollingInterval to 5 seconds.